# How can I dynamically change the Input value and user still can type decimal point in Chakra ui?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I use Chakra-UI to show a number input and take a reference from official document

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/number-input#create-a-mobile-spinner

I have two actions decide the input value that is first init and use trigger `setLimitInputValue` to change the value.

But when I try to set the value props, Input tag can not type decimal points anymore.

How do I achieve it in Chakra ui Input ?

```
import {
    Button,
    Input,
    useNumberInput,
    HStack,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

const appleValue = 0.6;
const samsungValue = 0.4;


const [limiInputValue, setLimitInputValue] = useState(appleValue);

    const {
        getInputProps: getLimitInputProps,
        getIncrementButtonProps: getIncLimitBtnProps,
        getDecrementButtonProps: getDescBtnProps,
    } = useNumberInput({
        step: 0.1,
        // value: limiInputValue, // I have to set this value props then I can dynamic change the value into <Input />, but Input can not type decimal point anymore
        defaultValue: limiInputValue,
        min: 0.01,
        max: 1.0,
        precision: 2,
        onChange: value => {
          const newValue = value.replace('-', '');
          setLimitInputValue(Number(newValue));
        },
    });

    const incLimitPrice = getIncLimitBtnProps();
    const decLimitPrice = getDescBtnProps();
    const inputLimitPrice = getLimitInputProps();


    return (
      <>
      <Button onClick={() => setLimitInputValue(samsungValue)} />
      <HStack mt={'16px'} gap={0} maxW="100%">
        <Button borderRadius={'6px 0px 0px 6px'} {...decLimitPrice}>
          -
        </Button>
        <Input
          textAlign={'center'}
          {...inputLimitPrice}
        />
        <Button borderRadius={'0px 6px 6px 0px'} {...incLimitPrice}>
          +
        </Button>
      </HStack>
      </>
    );
```